# Problem with colortbl and supertable, color width of the row with leading "@{}"

Tags: color, width, colortbl, supertabular

I have a problem with `colortbl` `\rowcolor` that insists on making the color width of the rows longer than the actual row width. Snippet of the code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english, norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, tabularx, fancyhdr, colortbl}
\usepackage[a5paper, height=18.0cm, inner=1.3cm, outer=0.65cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ttbnonum]{flowfram}

\twocolumn[1-2]

\begin{document}
\tiny
\begin{supertabular}{|p{0.38\linewidth}l@{\,}|lrl|}
   \multicolumn{5}{p{0.7\linewidth}}{\textbf{\raggedright \\ \footnotesize No name }} \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor[gray]{0.8} (project) (Ss) &  & \hspace{-8pt} Fp north & \hspace{-8pt} \textbf{3B:} & \hspace{-10pt}2 \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{1.0} (project) (!) &  & \hspace{-8pt} Fp north & \hspace{-8pt} \textbf{3C:} & \hspace{-10pt}2 \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{0.8} (project) (Ds) &  & \hspace{-8pt} Fp north & \hspace{-8pt} \textbf{5C:} & \hspace{-10pt}2b \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{1.0} (project) (Ss) &  & \hspace{-8pt} Fp north & \hspace{-8pt} \textbf{13A:} & \hspace{-10pt}7 \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{0.8} (project) &  & \hspace{-8pt} Fp north & \hspace{-8pt} \textbf{13B:} & \hspace{-10pt}1 \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{1.0} (project) (Ss) &  & \hspace{-8pt} Fp north & \hspace{-8pt} \textbf{13B:} & \hspace{-10pt}2 \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

The table expands across several pages (its genereated by some C++ code I'm making). The output looks like this:

[image]

The problem lies with the leading `@{}` in the definition of the `supertable` (I have to use super table since that is the only one compatible with `flowfram`).

I could put a negative `\hspace`, but that will still "indent" the second line in the `p{...}`.

(Been struggling with this one for 3 years now...)

Comment: Are you adding `@{}` by yourself to get rid of extra column space?

Comment: Of course you know that your code example does *not* produce the problem you're talking about.

Comment: Yup writing everything. I'm acutally making a pdf from some custom xml data files that I have, and I don't know up front what each single line will be (currently I have 900 "objects" in the xml file). Thus I must be carefull to make "everything" fit and look nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MWE can be simplified,

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}\makeatletter

\begin{tabular}{@{}|@{}p{0.38\linewidth}l@{\,}|lrl|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{red}(project)(Ss) &  &  Fp north &  \textbf{3B:} & \hspace{-10pt}2 \\
    (ddproject) (!) &  &  Fp north &  \textbf{3C:} & \hspace{-10pt}2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

shows the same behaviour

[image]

Looks like a bug to me, but can't look now, but I thought I would post the simplified MWE to help anyone looking at this.

It is a bug (I think) but you can avoid it by

```
 \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
```

you will then probably have to insert some spacing within the table to space things out a bot more.

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}|@{}p{0.38\linewidth}>{\hspace{12pt}}l|>{\hspace{12pt}}l>{\hspace{12pt}}r>{\hspace{12pt}}l|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{red}(project)(Ss) &  &  Fp north &  \textbf{3B:} & \hspace{-10pt}2 \\
    (ddproject) (!) &  &  Fp north &  \textbf{3C:} & \hspace{-10pt}2 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Hmm... That might work for me. The laatex code does'nt really have to be "neat" as its generated by a c++ program. Will try it out.

Comment: Tried it out. Its a good workaround for me. Now I can define the separators in a more understandable way: use positive values for the hspace. Super! thanks a lot!

Comment: Follow up question, David:
What does the @{} around the first "|" do, now that the colsep=0?

Comment: it doesn't do anything (actually it does do soemthing, it stopks TeX adding \hskip0pt in that place but mainly it is just left over from my trials)