# Package colortbl problem: wrong width of the colored row with ''@{}'' in column spec list

Tags: width, colortbl

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|@{}p{0pt}@{}}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan!70!black}
  Dummy & Text & \\[1em]
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For [some reason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column), I had to add a blank column at the end of the table, say `@{}p{0pt}@{}`. However, this behavior made the package `colortbl` sick. The width of the colored row didn't match the actual width of that row.

I searched TeX.SX and got [a similar  Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52548/problem-with-colortbl-and-supertable-color-width-of-the-row-with-leading). In the answer to that question, David Carlisle, the author of the package `colortbl`, suggests that `\tabcolsep` could be set to `0pt` and using `>{\hspace{}}` and `<{\hspace{}}`, from the package `array`, to insert extra space between columns.

Is there any better way to fix this problem (or both the two problems)? Any suggestion and/or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: the "some reason" only affects `m` columns, and you would not want the first `@{}` in that case. Currently if you use `@{}` anywhere then the workaround that yor refer to is probably all there is unless someone wants to suggest a patch to colortbl. For the alignment problem Frank posted an answer here with a modified `m` column that avoided the issue, I'll post a link if I find it.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column/174166#174166